# Opening remote files with Visual Studio Code using SSH from console

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, ssh, terminal, vscode-remote

Is it possible to open files on a remote host, which is accessible via SSH console, using Visual Studio Code, similar to the way we can do it on a local machine using the "code filename" command? Something like "code username@remote_host:/home/user/filename". Is there a way to achieve this, and does the remote-ssh extension have an API for it?